# MySQL dump to MariaDB issue with collation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, scripting, collation, automation

I have a django app running on a staging server (windows server 2012) with a MariaDB database. I have a git hook running mysqldump locally when I push to the staging branch. On the server I have a batch script pulling from this branch, migrating django migrations, import the dump and finally restarting the site. Looks a bit like this:

```
@echo off
D:
cd <repo>
cmd /k "git stuff && python manage.py migrate && mysql -uroot db < D:/repo/db.sql && stop/start site... && exit
PAUSE
```

Sadly though when the script reaches the dump import it spits out an error saying it doesn't know the collation (`ERROR 1273 (HY000) at line 25: Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'`
).
After some googling I found out I just have to open the sql in an editor and replace all 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci' with 'utf8mb4_general_ci'. Sure that works for this one time, that's not entirely useful for me as this dump is part of an automated process.

Does someone know a simple solution to automate the collation replacement?

Comment: on linux you can make `sed -e 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' -i myfilename.sql

Comment: I'm not on linux sadly

Comment: I feel your pain, but for a good while now, Microsoft is providing Linux utilities.  I can't imagine sed not being part of those.

Comment: well believe it or not.. "sed is not recognized..."

Comment: see if https://superuser.com/questions/1522245/equivalent-grep-and-sed-commands-on-windows/1522258 can help you fund a replacement, or simply don't switch databases

Comment: they're were made before I joined the project, don't have control over them unfortunately.

Comment: That collation is available only in MySQL 8.0.  Consider updating MySQL?  Did you recently change from MySQL to MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{ Related to @nbk's suggestion (in a [comment on the question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295954/mysql-dump-to-mariadb-issue-with-collation#comment578332_295954)) to use:
`sed -e 's/utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci/utf8mb4_unicode_ci/g' -i myfilename.sql`
}

I think there are two main options for running Unix commands in Windows:

1. "[Windows Subsystem for Linux Documentation (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/)" — this is provided by Microsoft. According to the "[Windows interoperability with Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-linux-tools-from-a-windows-command-line)" page, you should be able to run **sed** via the **wsl.exe** command, as in:

   ```
   C:\>wsl sed ...
   ```

   Please be aware that WSL2 requires Hyper-V and that *might* prevent VMWare and/or VirtualBox from working (if you use either or both of those). At first they didn't work with Hyper-V, then they did, then something in Windows changed and they stopped working with Hyper-V, and the current status is a little unclear (please see: [WSL2 breaks VirtualBox 6.1 #798](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/798) )
2. Many Unix/Linux commands have been ported to Windows via various 3rd party packages. The two that I am aware of are:

   - [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) — this project is actively maintained (most recent build is a few months ago). This is a fairly large project (currently 9907 "packages" - commands, libraries, etc), but I think you have the option to only install the components that you want. You can see the full list of packages [here](https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html).
   - [UnxUtils](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) — smaller project than Cygwin, and not currently maintained (most recent update is from 2014, and on a diff site; will give link in a moment), but I believe this one is lighter weight / easier to take one or two commands as there are no dependencies. There are two sites with files to download, and it's unclear which is newer, but I think I would go to this site: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ and get both the **UnxUtils.zip** and **UnxUpdates.zip** files.

In both cases you can get favorites such as: **sed**, **gawk**, etc.

Comment: unicode gave me some insert errors, but replacing it with general did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas96 You are welcome. Can you please share exactly what you did to solve this? Which solution did you go with? If you did go with `sed`, what was the pattern and replacement string that worked for you?